# Getting insertBefore error when changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Get a insertBefore errorwhen changing the state

categoryInfo is an array of objects. When calling the api readRelationById it reloads the array of objects if something is added or deleted in the database.

```
getInfo= (id) => {
        Api.readRelationById(id)
            .then(res => this.setState({categoryInfo: res}))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };
```

how the list is rendering

```
<select multiple onChange={onRemoveChange(props)} size="10" style={{width: '500px'}}>
     {props.categoryInfo !== undefined ? props.categoryInfo.map((item, index) => {
          return <option value={item.id}key={index}>{item.id} {item.description}</option>
          }) : <option disabled> N/A </option>}
</select>
```

error message

```
NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's going to be more error afterward, but first off, you should definitely change this:

```
<select multiple onChange={onRemoveChange(props)} ...
```

to this:

```
<select multiple onChange={() => onRemoveChange(props)} ...
```

so as to pass a function, and not a value evaluated from a function.